# Microsoft Access query combine multiple records by ID

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2007 on windows 7 Enterprise
I apologize if this has been covered, but I couldn't find it.
In a table where i have:

ID.....info....   place....   because

1.....      abc ...   home.....    fridge

1 ....     abc ...   work.......    desk

1.....      abc....    play.......    pockets

I would like a query that the result is

Id.. info....as1 ....    as1......    as2.....    as2 ....   as3  ... as3

1....abc...home...fridge...  work...  desk...   play..   pockets

the number of results by ID may vary, and the "Place and because" may not be the same.

any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any field or combination of fields that can be used to uniquely identify each record?

Comment: First, last, comanyID

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a column that uniquely identifies each row:

```
ID    info    place    because    id
1     abc     home     fridge     1
1     abc     work     desk       2
1     abc     play     pockets    3
```

Then, a union query to have all the records in a single column:

```
ID    info    rowID    key       value     name
1     abc     1        place     home      as_1_place
1     abc     1        because   fridge    as_1_because
1     abc     2        place     work      as_2_place
1     abc     2        because   desk      as_2_because
1     abc     3        place     play      as_3_place
1     abc     3        because   pockets   as_3_because
```

Then you want a crosstab query on the name field

```
ID    info    as1_place    as1_because    as2_place    as2_because  as3_place  as3_because
```

I will elaborate on this shortly.